# Periodic "resolving host" on Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, hosts

I am using Windows 8.1 and periodically (every few hours on an average day) get a "resolving host" message in Chrome. Despite the fact I am still connected to my wifi router, `ping 8.8.8.8` will also cease to work. (Request timed out) I've tried using three different wifi adapters and two different routers. I don't have this issue on any other device. I confirmed via `nslookup` that my router is pushing opendns (208.67.220.123) to my devices. How can I diagnose this problem? Thank you!

Comment: if ping is also failing, then this is a general network failure, not directly related to hostname resolution at all. What DNS server you are using is imaterial. The issue as you describe it seems to be a flapping wifi link.

Comment: @FrankThomas How could I confirm that?

Comment: try pinging your wifi router/ap both when everything is working, and when it fails. if ping fails only when chrome freaks out, then the issue is your wifi connection.

Comment: @FrankThomas Confirmed! So I need a new router or adapter?

Comment: That will take some study of the issue. do other devices go in and out the way this one does? does moving closer to the AP, or removing sources of interference help, etc? if everything else is fine, I'd lean toward the NIC, but if the other devices are simmillarly affected, then replacing the router/ap would probably be benificial. Nowadays they are cheap devices that aren't expected to last more than a couple years.

Comment: Moving closer helps and no other devices have issues, so...

Comment: unfourtunately, that makes it environmental. if you have concerns about the NIC being flakey then replacing it may help. another good option is to install a second AP closer to where you are.

Comment: I'm working on a second AP now... http://superuser.com/questions/1002341/airrouter-wired-connections-working-ap-is-not

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, sounds like you may have already done this, "ping 8.8.8.8", but just in case this is how I fixed the problem.

There is a superb explanation here for Win7/8/8.1: http://www.webnots.com/correct-chrome-resolving-host-issue/

This is actually Win7 directions, but should be very similar for Win 8.1 -- I actually bought this pc with 8.1, gave it 2 months, then bought Win7 and downgraded my OS.

Solution:
Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections -> Local Area Connection: Networking tab : Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IP)
-- Then click properties on click IP Version 4.

Bottom portion: DNS
Preferred DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
Alternate DNS: 192.168.1.1 or 8.8.4.4

Comment: Not helping....