# AirRouter wired connections working, AP is not

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I recently added a Ubiquiti AirRouter to my network. (Let's call this AR) It is wired to my TP-Link router (Let's call this TP) which is wired to my modem.

TP is my DHCP server. Wired clients to AR are reflected in the TP clients list, and can access the internet. They do receive an ip within the TP DHCP range (192.168.4.1 to 192.168.4.254). Wireless clients, according to their `ipconfig` and the AR clients list, attempt to use a 169.x address.

These are the AR settings:

[image]
[image]

These are the TP settings:

[image]
[image]

`ipconfig` for a wired connection to either device looks like this:

[image]

`ipconfig` for a wireless connection to AR looks like this:

[image]

I can post more of the settings or anything else needed to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you putting AR on a different IP subnet than TP? Why are you having AR act as a DHCP relay to a (possibly non-existent?) DHCP server? What other interfaces of the AR are attached to BRIDGE0?

Comment: Does every device in your network use a 255.255.0.0 netmask? Does the DHCP server assign IPs with this subnet mask? Are you trying to just use the AR as a switch and access point? Or are you trying to use it to do actual routing?

Comment: @Spiff The mask should always be 255.255.0.0. TP (at 192.168.1.1) is my DHCP server. Nothing else is attached to BRIDGE0 I don't think...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes everything is 255.255.0.0. I believe it does (Please see the ipconfig results). I only want AR to be a switch and AP. Thank you!

Comment: @GiantDuck If you only want it to be a switch and an AP, why does it have two IP addresses assigned to it?

Comment: @GiantDuck Maybe setting AR to be a DHCP Relay causes it to filter out DHCP requests instead of bridging them with all other traffic, and maybe TP's DHCP server wasn't designed/tested to work with a DHCP Relay, so maybe it's doing something wrong when those DHCP requests are forward to it via the relay. Try completely disabling the DHCP service in AR and see if that allows the clients' DHCP requests to be directly bridged through to TP. Also, make sure you have it configured to bridge, not route, between WLAN and WAN. I see you have NAT off, but it could be acting as a normal IP router.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Because BRIDGE0 and WLAN0 have different MAC addresses.

Comment: Why would a bridge have a MAC address? Why would a LAN interface that's just bridged have a MAC address? Only the router's own interface should have a MAC address and, thus, an IP address. And that interface should be part of the single bridge.

Comment: @Spiff Just tried disabling the DHCP server and no dice. What I find most puzzling is that a device wired to LAN0 successfully receives an IP from TP and can access the internet, but connections to WLAN0 do not and can not. I'll try changing network mode to bridge now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the Ubiquiti AirRouter User Guide, you almost certainly have AR in "Router" or "SOHO Router" mode, when you need it to be in "Bridge" mode.

Note that disabling NAT does not enable Bridge mode. Disabling NAT just makes it a traditional IP router (routing between two IP subnets without translating/masquerading IP addresses).

Switch it to Bridge mode and it should work the way you want.